# Kicked out back to login. No cinnamon installed

Tags: login

I have a clean install of 13.10 without Cinnamon. I used it happily for a while, until it stopped letting me in: after I type in the password, it kicks me back to the password prompt. The only unusual thing that I did before that was using pm-hibernate (after which this command did not work the second time).

I saw the related posts, tried removing .Xauthority, resetting permissions on the home directory etc., nothing helps.

Please help me out!

Meir

Comment: Based on another post, I looked into .xsession-errors. It says: <br> /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 25: export: : bad variable name. Could this be the reason? BTW, there is no export directive on line 25 of that file...

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue a couple of times, appeared to be something corrupted in my user profile. Removing the following files and directory located in your userdir always gives me back my login:

```
.cache/
.Xauthority 
.ICEAuthority
```

You can do so by opening a terminalscreen (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) logging in and do:

```
rm -rf .cache
rm .Xauthority
rm .ICEAutority
```

No go back with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, login and (hopefully) be happy again.
The disadvantage is you reset your unity icons and preferences.

Comment: Did this and restarted. The problem persists...

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to restart the system before it took effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a mistake in the path in the export of $PYTHONPATH in my .profile. Commenting out that line fixed the problem...